# Difference between logical "and" and bit wise &

Tags: python, bitwise-operators, logical-operators

I was writing a piece of code for a practice problem where I was trying the display the highest odd number. I kept running into a problem where when I was linking two statements together with a & symbol it was coming as true even though when evaluated separately the second statement was false. when I changed from & to and instead it then started to evaluate correctly. the code I wrote is below.

```
x = 21
y = 57
z = 7

a = x
if x > y:
    a = y
    if y > z:
        a = z
elif x > z:
    a = z


if x%2 != 0:
    a = x
if y%2 != 0 & (y > a):
    a = y
if z%2 != 0 & (z > a):
    a = z
print(z%2 != 0 & (z > a))
print(z%2 != 0 and (z > a))
print(a)
```

The output was

```
True
False
7
```

Why do you get different outputs for & and "and". Aren't they the same?

I was reading that & is checking the actual bits of the value in question while and is evaluating the expression. Also & is supposed to be a "lazy" form of checking.

Comment: You got it backwards -- `and` is lazy, insofar as if the value on the left is falsey there's no reason to calculate the value on the right. (And in `or`, if the thing on the left is truthy, there's no reason to calculate the thing on the right -- but `|` can't be lazy, because you need to calculate both values if you're going to combine them bit-by-bit).

Answer (score -1):

> && is the logical AND operator.

*It can combine two boolean expressions* and returns true if both expressions are true, otherwise, false. It's used for logical operations.

> & is a bitwise AND operator.

It performs a *bitwise AND operation on each bit of its operands*. It is typically used for manipulating individual bits within integer values.

Comment: In [How to Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer), note the section _Answer Well-Asked Questions_ and the bullet point therein regarding questions that have been "asked and answered many times before".

Comment: (and in Python, logical and is `and`, not `&&`; I don't know for a fact why you were downvoted, but that would be my guess).